# While loops boolean reassignment

Tags: java

Say I have a do-while loop like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = false;
        int i = 1;
        do {
            i++;
        } while (b = !b);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

What would cause `i` to increment a total of three? I can understand this loop will ensure that it will be ran at least once, but in this case the boolean `b` is being reassigned to true, wouldn't that cause an infinite loop?

Comment: `b = !b` flips `b` to the opposite, whatever it is.  The first time, `b` starts out as `false` so it's reassigned to `true`.  The second time, `b` starts out as `true`, so it's reassigned to `false`, and then the loop exits.  I hope this is an exercise to test your understanding of Java. **Never** write code like this in real life, with an assignment to a boolean variable doubling as a condition.  It's hard to follow.

Comment: Yes, this is an exercise question. Thank you for your explanation, I didn't catch the other piece where it would be flipped back to false, examples like these can be very frustrating to understand. I appreciate it!

Comment: @ajb any particular reason _not_ to post that as answer?

Comment: @BenKnoble probably just a preference not to post really short answers if I don't feel like providing a more in-depth explanation...

Comment: @ajb fair enough. Plus, you arent way down in ge low rep league where that would matter as much anyways i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is explaination of your code..

- intially value of  `b=false i=1;`
- enter in loop and increment `i=2`;
- check `while` condition `b=!b` means  `b=true`;
- again goto loop and and increment `i=3`;
- check `while` condition `b=!b` mean `b=fase` and exit from
  `while` loop
- now come to `SOP` and `print` `i`'s value that is `3`
  and exit from program

Answer (score 2):

Before loop, `i = 1` and `b = false`.

```
----------+--------+--------+
Pass      | 1      | 2      |
----------+--------+--------+
i         | 2      | 3      |
----------+--------+--------+
b         | false  | true   |
----------+--------+--------+
condition | !false | !true  | //loop breaks
----------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things are to be noted here. `b=!b` as condition check means that assign complement value of `b` and then check for condition satisfaction. As we know do-while loop executes at least once, the values goes to three.